# Remove hyphen at the end of string in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a column of a dataframe in R like this:

```
names <- data.frame(name=c("ABC", "ABC-D", "ABCD-"))
```

I would like to remove the hyphen at the end of the strings while maintaining the hyphen in the middle of them. I've tried a few expressions like:

```
names$name <- gsub("+-\\w", "", names$name)
# the desired output is "ABC", "ABC-D", and "ABCD", respectively
```

While several combinations remove the hyphens entirely, I'm not sure how to specify the string boundary and the hyphen together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
gsub("\\-$", "", names$name)
# [1] "ABC"   "ABC-D" "ABCD"
```

`$` tells `R` that the (escaped) hyphen is at the end of the word

Although, as the `-` is placed first in the `regex` you don't need to escape it so this works too:

```
gsub("-$", "", names$name)
#[1] "ABC"   "ABC-D" "ABCD"
```

Comment: Excellent. I knew it had to be simple (but oddly missing from Google searches). Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome. I'm far from an expert in `regex` but this one was in my skills ;-)